# How is the homogeneous solution of a linear different equation "transformed" using method of undetermined coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations, homogeneous-equation

DE: $x^3y'''+4x^2y''-5xy'-15y=x^4$

Making the substitution $y=x^m$ to develop the characteristic equation $m^3+m^2-7m-15=0$ gives roots of $3,-2{\pm}i$. From this homogeneous general solution is

$c_1e^{3x}+e^{-2x}(c_2\cos (x)+c_3\sin(x))$.

Solving using method of undetermined coefficients, Kreyszig suggests if $r(x)$ is in $x^n$ form to assume a solution in the form of $K_nx^n+K_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+K_0$. Doing this ends with a particular solution of $x^4/37$.

I have access to the solution, which is $y=(1/x^2)(c_2\cos(\ln x)+c_3\sin(\ln x))+c_1x^3 + x^4/37$.

Why was the substitution $x=\ln x$ done in the homogeneous portion of the solution?

Thank you.

[I am using Advanced Engineering Mathematics by Kreyszig for reference]

Edit: I actually just read that method of undetermined coefficients is only for constant coefficients, in this case $x$ isn't constant so I am not sure why it worked out for the particular solution, maybe I got lucky.

Comment: Euler 's equation the substitution with $u=\ln (x)$ is well known

Comment: @isham but why am I having to use that substitution in this solution? I thought $y=x^m$ was sufficient, why do I have to also use $x=e^u$, assuming that my actual homogeneous solution is using u instead of x?

Comment: @Isham but when I use $y=x^m$ it definitely didn't transform it correctly because my solution was not correct in the homogeneous portion. Or maybe I am not understanding your comment.

Comment: Well $u=\ln(x)$ is used to transform Euler s equaion into a differential equation with constantt coefficient....I used that I never used the other method for this type of equation

Comment: @Isham AHH nvm, I thnk I understand. Because I assumed a general solution in exponential form, I need to assume $x^4$ is also exponential, giving $e^u$ where $u=lnx$. Now my solution has $u$ in it, which I can substitute back in later.

Comment: Yes try that ...for complex solution  $a \pm ib$ the solution is $e^{ax}\cos(b\ln(x))+e^{ax}\sin(b\ln(x)) $

Comment: Okay that makes more sense in my why solution was incorrect. Thank you.

Comment: Yep thats were the problem was..lol when you use the $x^m$ substitution you have to be carefull with the solution of the differential equation....